# EAV Model Product - Loading too heavy

Tags: magento2, performance, eav

Our website's using Magento 2 platform. Number of product and number of product's attributes keep growing faster.It leads to heavy loading when getting product's information(using EAV Model).In product detail page, we can optimize by indexing the product information to other server. But how can we optimize in checkout flow?. We cannot use flat product table because number of attribute is quite large(limited column in MYSQL table).